# Working with a var outside Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell, variables, for-loop

I have this code which works as it should:

```
Get-Content $path\$newName -Encoding OEM |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '<Num:(\d{8,20})>$','$1'}| Set-Content $path\$txtName -Encoding UTF8
```

The string is replaced by the digits. But I would like to be able to use $1 outside the loop.

Like:

```
write-host $1
```

For example. But if i do this noting is output.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [VivekKumarSingh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50579425/6811411)s script.

```
$InFile = '.\test.txt'
$OutFile= '.\test2.txt'
$RegEx = "<Num:(\d{8,20})>$"
$array = @()
Get-Content $InFile -Encoding OEM | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match $RegEx ){$array += $matches[1]}
        $_ -replace $RegEx,"`$1"
} | Set-Content $OutFile -Encoding UTF8
$array
```

---

```
> gc .\test.txt
<Num:1234567890>
<Num:23456789101112>

> .\SO_50579315.ps1
1234567890
23456789101112

> gc .\test2.txt
1234567890
23456789101112
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. But there seems to be a linebreak in $array. Like so: $array+'rrr'  Is this preventable?

Comment: This actually works:  $faxnr = `` $array=$array -replace "`n","" `` BUT gives an error: ` : The term '`' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
 a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\FaxOut\fax.ps1:31 char:18
+         $faxnr = `` $array=$array -replace "`n","" ``
+                  ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (`:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I'm not sure you are quoting strings properly with either single `'` or double quotes `"`. The backtick `\`` is used to escape line end or special chars in strings. The RegEx above should only replace/match digits.

Comment: I solved it by doint this: $faxnr = $array[0]. It works great now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be assigning `$1` to an array like this -

```
$array = @()
Get-Content $path\$newName -Encoding OEM | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '<Num:(\d{8,20})>$','$1'; $array += $1 } | Set-Content $path\$txtName -Encoding UTF8
```

You can use the values of `$1` like `$array[0]`, `$array[1]`, `$array[2]`.. and so on.

Comment: Thank you. Tthis gives me: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'To'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, 
and then try the command again.

Comment: If i write-host $array[0] nothing is printed.

Comment: Nice idea, but the `$1` capture group is only valid in the replace. The `$matches` collection is more persistent.

Comment: @LotPings - True that. The `$matches` will catch the regex more effectively. Again thanks for the wonderful tip.